# What is the difference between 隠す and 覆う?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words

It would be really nice if someone could explain the difference between these two words that both mean ´to hide´. Some example sentences that illustrate the difference would really help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

隠す means "hide", but 覆う means "cover", "overlay" and "wrap".

覆い隠す means "to hide something from sight with a cover"

Some example sentenses of 覆う. https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A6%86%E3%81%86